# Apache2 server on raspberry pi will not run any php scripts

Tags: php, apache

I have set up an apache2 server on the pi, but when trying to run any php file (placed in /var/www/html) the web page just responds with HTTP error 500. I have ran the index.html file and it works fine its only when php scripts are run that it gives me an error. I have also made sure that the php5 module is enabled in the apache configuration settings. Any advice on what to test from here would greatly help.

Update: Seems there was a problem with the permissions of the file. By giving read and write privileges by all users to the file it worked.

Comment: Tried the error log?

Comment: This is what it states [Tue Jun 07 14:43:47.687863 2016] [:error] [pid 21715] [client 10.1.10.35:54937] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 07 14:43:47.688249 2016] [:error] [pid 21715] [client 10.1.10.35:54937] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sql test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: General rule: if a webserver spits out a 500 error, your FIRST stop in the debugging chain should be to look at the error log.